# Android - Request SQLite query to be sorted based on relationship between two columns

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by

Is there any way to query a `Cursor` with the content sorted based on the row's relationship between two columns?

For example, if I had two columns in my table:

1. Basketball shots made
2. Basketball shots attempted

is there any way I query a `Cursor` with the data sorted based on the "shot percentage" (i.e. made/attempted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in order to get accurate sorting, you might need to cast to `DOUBLE`  (the above suggestions does integer division which didn't provide correct results in all cases):

```
ORDER BY CAST(ShotsMade AS DOUBLE)/ShotsAttempted DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query, put `ORDER BY ShotsMade/ShotsAttempted DESC`.

Comment: Wow... it's that easy? I'll try that out! Just to clarify, will SQL perform integer addition here? Do I need to make one of the columns have type "DECIMAL"? Don't know much about SQL other than some simple Android stuff :).

Comment: awesome! turns out I didn't need to add anything else. thanks a lot, man!

Comment: Welcome to the world of SQL! It's a pretty powerful system for managing your data.